# How to test if stream emits a value at a particular position in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

If I have a stream that emits objects of `Dog`.

```
Stream<Dog> dogStream;
```

```dart
class Dog {
  final String name;
  final String breed;

  Dog(this.name, this.breed);
}
```

I want to test for the name emitted in 4th value.

So I want to ignore the first 3 values emitted by the `stream` and check if the 4th value is equal to say `foo`. How to check at a particular position?

PS: There are hacky ways of doing it, like using `expectInOrder`, but my test should not care about the first 3 values emitted, and if I want to check for 8th or say 20th value, it doesn't make sense to use `expectInOrder`.

Comment: Have a look at [elementAt()](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.0/dart-async/Stream/elementAt.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `elementAt` or skip first 3 values of the stream and check emitted item:

```dart
test('stream', () async {
  Stream<int> stream() => Stream.fromIterable([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

  expect(await stream().elementAt(3), 4);
  expect(stream().skip(3), emitsInOrder(<dynamic>[4]));
  expect(stream().skip(3), emits(4));
});
```